# CSS & HTML: Menu-Bar <a> and <li> tags not in line

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm trying to make a menu bar that is divided in three columns, where the left and the right side are links HOME and SEARCH, but in the center part of the menu there are several links nested inside a list. The columns are showing nicely, but for some mystical reason the HOME and SEARCH links are shown higher than the center content. I tried nesting the links HOME and SEARCH inside lists as well, but then everything in the menu-bar offsets to the right by a little bit and I would love it to be symmetrical without using padding or margins if possible.

It's probably something very simple and absolutely my fault, but here's me hoping.

So the question is how to either disable the offset to the right or how to make everything be on one line without using those in my opinion unnecessary `<li>`?

```css
nav {
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav div {
  display: inline;
}

.area-center .menu li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: none;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.area-right {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: right;
}

.area-center {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}

.area-left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_bar">
  <nav id="main-menu" class="section">
    <div class="area-left">
      <a class="order">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="area-center">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="order"><a class="order">a</a></li>
        <li class="order"><a class="order">b</a></li>
        <li class="order"><a class="order">c</a></li>
        <li class="order"><a class="order">d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="area-right">
      <a class="order">SEARCH</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers sets the default margin to `<ul>` elements if you didn't specify it. You can see this in below image

[image]

You have to set `margin:0` to your `<ul>`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
nav {
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav div {
  display: inline;
}

.area-center .menu li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: none;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.area-right {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: right;
}

.area-center {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}

.area-left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: left;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_bar">
  <nav id="main-menu" class="section">
    <div class="area-left">
      <a class="order">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="area-center">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="order"><a class="order">a</a></li>
        <li class="order"><a class="order">b</a></li>
        <li class="order"><a class="order">c</a></li>
        <li class="order"><a class="order">d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="area-right">
      <a class="order">SEARCH</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding **line-height** to **area-left** & **area-right**, maybe this isn't the best way, you can find better way

```css
nav{
    padding-left: 3em;
    padding-right: 3em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
nav div{
    display:inline;
}
.area-center .menu li{
    display:inline;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-top:none;
}
.menu ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
}
.menu li{
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
}
.menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.area-right{
    float: left; 
    width: 20%;
    line-height:45px;
    text-align: right;
}

.area-center{  
    float: left; width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
}
.area-left{
    float: left; 
    width: 20%;
    line-height:45px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_bar">
            <nav id="main-menu" class="section">
                <div class="area-left">
                    <a class="order">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div class="area-center">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li class="order"><a class="order">a</a></li>
                        <li class="order"><a class="order">b</a></li>
                        <li class="order"><a class="order">c</a></li>
                        <li class="order"><a class="order">d</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="area-right">
                    <a class="order">SEARCH</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in your CSS. `.menu ul` doesn't exist.

Update the selector to simply `.menu`, and also remove the default `margin` applied to the `ul` by the browser.

```css
nav {
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav div {
  display: inline;
}

.area-center .menu li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: none;
}


/* this is incorrect
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}*/

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.area-right {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: right;
}

.area-center {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}

.area-left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_bar">
  <nav id="main-menu" class="section">
    <div class="area-left">
      <a class="order">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="area-center">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="order"><a class="order">a</a></li>
        <li class="order"><a class="order">b</a></li>
        <li class="order"><a class="order">c</a></li>
        <li class="order"><a class="order">d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="area-right">
      <a class="order">SEARCH</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```